# Realm Android Decryption issue

Tags: android, realm

When I try to access the realm db after installing the app, I'm getting the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong key used to decrypt Realm.

This is the method which return realm instance:

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(mContext)
            .name(dbname)
            .schemaVersion(0) 
            .migration(new DataBaseMigration()) 
            .encryptionKey(key)
            .build();

    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
    return realm;
```

I am getting the error in the following line.

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
```

Help me to solve this issue. I am using realm 0.85 version.

Comment: The `key` has to be the same everything you get an instance of your Realm. Is the Realm file distributed with the app or do you get the error message the second time, you run the app?

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Issue fixed.